# Extract polygons by color from mask image

Tags: python, opencv, shapes

I would like to extract the Polygon Shape by color, if it's possible the corner coordinates, [image: example of mask]

Currently i'm trying with open-cv find contourns, but it's very **precise** i'm getting a lot of coordinates. what i want it's just the corner points to make the polygon by color.

```
img = cv2.imread('mask_ZT76_39_A_2_8.png', 0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)
thresh =     cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

approx_=[]

for i in range(len(contours[0])):
  epsilon = cv2.arcLength(contours[0][i],True)
  approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contours[0][i],epsilon,True)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find corners points of a shape in an image in opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50984205/how-to-find-corners-points-of-a-shape-in-an-image-in-opencv)

Comment: I tried with that solution. but it's just getting very few points.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @anms_pro sure, maybe will help you `Measure region properties` https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_regionprops.html