# Find Corner of Sliding Window in Python With Accuracy

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I Want Find Corner of Sliding Window I Tried a lot of algorithm and project based on Python but none of them work perfectly here my code.

```py
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from bisect import bisect_left
from PIL import Image


img = cv2.imread('img2.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,0)


contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


## only draw contour that have big areas
imx = img.shape[0]
imy = img.shape[1]
lp_area = (imx * imy) / 10

for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)

    if len(approx) == 4 and cv2.contourArea(cnt) > lp_area:
        print("rectangle")
        tmp_img = img.copy()
        cv2.drawContours(tmp_img, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 255), 2)
        topleft = (approx[0,0,0],approx[0,0,1])
        bottomright = (approx[2,0,0],approx[2,0,1])
        topright = (approx[3,0,0],approx[3,0,1])
        bottomleft = (approx[1,0,0],approx[1,0,1])
        cv2.circle(tmp_img, topleft, 8, (0, 50, 255), -1)
        cv2.circle(tmp_img, bottomright, 8, (0, 255, 255), -1)
        cv2.circle(tmp_img, topright, 8, (255, 50, 0), -1)
        cv2.circle(tmp_img, bottomleft, 8, (255, 255, 0), -1)
        
     
        cv2.waitKey(0)


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

| My Excepted result : | My result: | Original Image (Img3.jpg) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [My Excepted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPFVA.png) | [My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqFQW.png) | [Img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQtpD.jpg) |

[Origin of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860785/opencv-using-canny-and-shi-tomasi-to-detect-round-corners-of-a-playing-card)

So, here's my question:

1. **What best way to find sliding window?**
2. **What can I Improve to get better result?**
3. **Does my code useful?**

I tried to find sliding window and result can't be perfect.
Method I tried:

1. Otsu plus contour detection doesn't work very well
2. Different Threshold doesn't work very well
3. Contour with different Approx doesn't work very well.

Sorry for my bad English I'm not native speaker.

Comment: Threshold on the white (or brown) part of the window using cv2.inRange(). Use morphology to clean up a little or filter with contours.

Comment: It's going to depend a lot on the images you have and how similar they are.